# Regex alternation doesn't work as expected

Tags: regex, prometheus

Here is my regex:

```
^\/(var\/lib\/docker|kubelet)|(run\/docker\/netns\/).*
```

Here are the strings which need to be caught.

```
/var/lib/docker/pods/9bbc0d82-be96-11e8-9217
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/9bbc0d82-be96-11e8-9217
```

This catches "/var/lib/docker" but not "/var/lib/kubelet" .
What am I missing here?

I am using this in node_exporter service file, so not sure even which regex flavor does it use.

Comment: Your parentheses are misplaced: you tell the engine to capture either `var\/lib\/docker` on one side or `kebelet` on the other. Factorize and you should be done.

Comment: To match either of them try using an alternation `(?:docker|kubelet)` in a non capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

The positioning of parenthesis makes the alternative either `var/lib/docker` or `kubelet`. If you want the alternatives to be `docker` or `kubelet`, it should be something like this:

```
^\/(var\/lib\/(docker|kubelet))|(run\/docker\/netns\/).*
```

Notice the parenthesis enclosing "docker|kubelet" instead of:

```
(var\/lib\/docker|kubelet)"
```

Comment: Put the alternation in a non-capturing group (i.e., `(?:docker|kubelet)` ) _[as someone said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)_ to avoid disrupting the order of the capturing groups.

Comment: Great this almost did what I wanted but it puts "docker" or "kubelet" words under separate group, while doing (?:docker|kubelet) as mentioned by @The fourth bird - keeps the group together.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a non capturing group `(?:docker|kubelet)` or else you would match either `/var/lib/docker` or `/kubelet`.

`\/(var\/lib\/(?:docker|kubelet))|(run\/docker\/netns\/).*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ibIULN/1)